# CSS image pop up

Tags: html, image, popup, hover

I have a html page with 12 thumbnails (spliced Photoshop) within a table (Table_01) within a div and when you hover over one of the thumbs a new image pops up.

At the moment when you hover over the "Ice white" thumb (this is the one I'm testing with at the moment) the new image pops up at the top of the page.

This is no good. It needs to pop up exactly to the right of the div which Table_01 is contained in (preferably top of pop up image flush with top of div and left side of pop up image touching right side of div if that makes sense). CSS is within head of source code near the end. It's not the best written webpage and is very messily coded but this bit should be easy to weed out and identify a solution hopefully. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Late response obviously but I hope, it will help you out anyways.
As far as your comments above, those popping out new images needs to have absolute position with some right and top positions fixes. For example, considering that you are having a 3 divs in a row, each div is having an image, you should mention the parent div (containing the image) to have relative position; inside it the image (actually the popup image or thumb) should have position absolute and then it should have right and top adjustments in CSS as per your requirement.
I hope it will help you out...